# Unable to restore or update or install nuget package in vs 2022

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, nuget, restore, access-denied

When I'm trying to run asp.net core webapi empty project which will use swagger to show data output in a webpage, I'm getting error cannot start my_path\webapp.exe , project.assets.json not found and when tried to restore the nuget packages it gives error "access path access denied"

Comment: try restarting your pc and see if the problem persists.

Comment: After restart also the problem is not resolved

Comment: Not resolved after restarting pc

Comment: Check "VIew > Error List" menu option in Visual Studio to see errors which you are getting. Post the errors here for the community to help you futher.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NETSDK1004 Assets file 'C:\Users\varun\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. WebApplication2 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets 267

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Access to the path 'C:\Users\varun\.nuget\packages\microsoft.openapi\1.2.3' is denied.